# bash script for replace text from two file in one

Tags: xml, bash

I have two file xml; en.xml and it.xml

in the default file language en.xml I have this structure

```
<string key="City is not set">
    <tr lang="en"> City is not set </tr>
```

in the file It.xml I have:

```
<string key="Citt&agrave; non &egrave; impostato">
    <tr lang="it">  </tr>
```

In that way I can extract data from it.xml and put in to en.xml ?

from en.xml I need to get string key

```
<string key="City is not set">
```

in the second file it.xml I need to change:

```
<string key="Citt&agrave; non &egrave; impostato">
```

in to :

```
<tr lang="it"> Citt&agrave; non &egrave; impostato </tr>
```

my goal is to obtain a final result:

```
<string key="City is not set">
    <tr lang="it"> Citt&agrave; non &egrave; impostato </tr>
```

I hope is clear.

Comment: It is clear, but parsing XML with bash is not very indicated. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I try to write a bash script using grep, sed and tr but is very complicate for me....

Comment: Use an xml processing tool for this. xslt or possibly xmlstarlet or python/perl/ruby/etc.

Comment: with xslt online tools  I have a problem because each file have  24000 line, now I try with xmlstarlet

Answer (score 0):

I use this to parse my xml:

```
get_data () {
local tag=$1
local xml=$2

# Find tag in the xml, convert tabs to spaces, remove leading spaces, remove the tag.
grep $tag $xml | \
    tr '\011' '\040' | \
    sed -e 's/^[ ]*//' \
        -e 's/^<.*>\([^<].*\)<.*>$/\1/'
}
get_data \<tag_name\> filename.xml | tee output.txt
cat output.txt
```

and then add a bunch of extra if else commands relating to input, some prompts and stuff, and you've got yourself a functionable xml parser.

I use this with a curl command to parse xml feeds from newspapers, and my personal favourite [rssmaker](http://www.fbrss.com).

Also, here's [the source](http://www.threadstates.com/articles/2011/parsing-xml-in-bash.html).

Have fun!